# How i can do a reset in a smartwatch with Android 5.1?

Tags: android, wearables

I have a Kw88 smartwatch and in the last charge it's doesn't turn on. I have looked for a reset or trying something to get the watch on. Anyone could help me? I also tried took off the battery, and nothing happens.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer. This is a site for programming questions.

Comment: Thanks! I already have the smartwatch working. I simply disconnect the battery for a hour. Then I could charge and turn on the device.